# Getting started deploying Craft sites with Capistrano

Tags: deployment

I'd like to deploy a Craft site with [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) but am looking for the best way to get started.

Is the [Craft Deploy](https://github.com/Bluegg/craft-deploy) utility by Bluegg up to date, or would it be better to use a vanilla version of Capistrano? I'm curious because there doesn't seem to be a lot of activity on the github account for the utility.

For anyone with experience using the Craft Deploy utility, are there any caveats for bringing the Craft Deploy utility into an existing project? The instructions tell how to use it when setting up a new project but not an existing one.